# MySQL LIKE statement

Tags: mysql

I have the following query in MySQL

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_instagram`
WHERE category LIKE '%enter%'
```

When this query run it's return these values:

```
   ID    Value
--------------------
    1     enter 
    12    entertainment
    23    Augmenter
    45    enter
    53    enter, fitness
    74    weight lifting, enter, coaches
```

I want only those column hold **matching** value pass in where statement

```
    ID    Value
--------------------
    1     enter
    45    enter
    53    enter, fitness
    74    weight lifting, enter, coaches
```

How I achieve this?

Comment: drop the `%`. the `%` tells mysql that at that point there might come other characters.

Comment: Reading [the MySQL docs on `LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) would be informative here.  `%` is a _wildcard_ character.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT AS QUESTION WAS UPDATED**

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_instagram`
    WHERE category LIKE 'enter' 
    OR category LIKE 'enter,%' 
    OR category LIKE '%, enter'
```

Something like above should work, there might be variations on the `'enter'` patterns `('enter', 'enter,%', '%, enter')` but I think I got them all.

The '%' is a wildcard.

[READ THE MYSQL DOCS ON 'LIKE'](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_instagram`
WHERE category = 'enter'
```

Comment: It is not correct as an answer but it is also lacking any explanation why this should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_instagram`
WHERE category = 'enter'
```

Comment: This answer is very bare-bones. Please add some explanation how and why this is a solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: this is was he was needed, to find values that are matched to some criteria

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use simply:

`SELECT *
FROM`wp_instagram
`WHERE category='enter'`

Or this works too:

`SELECT *
FROM`wp_instagram
`WHERE category like 'enter'`

% in `%enter%` is there for any characters preceding and any characters following.